# Publishing on arXiv in preparation for WWW conference

Tags: publications, conference, computer-science

There's a framework I've been working on and I'm interested to release it to the open source and research community but I'd also really like to publish it at the upcoming [WWW conference](http://www.www2017.com.au/).

Is it against the rules of that conference to pre-publish a paper I later submit there, or at least the crux of such a paper, on a site like [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

Since the conference will make  the papers from the proceedings open access ["The proceedings of WWW are published online (open access) and through ACM Digital Library, and it is considered one of the most impactful conferences in computer science."](http://www.www2017.com.au/call-for-papers/) I don't think the arxiv preprint should be a problem. However, you should e-mail first to the WWW2017 committee to see if this is against the rules.